# Object reference error after ASP.NET 5 Web Site creation

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

When using Visual Studio Enterprise RC to create a new .NET Framework 4.6 ASP.NET Application using the Web Site template I am receiving an object reference not set to an instance of an object error. After dismissing the error the project seems to be ok, but I would like to be sure.

Both the Empty and Web API template work fine.

I have tried creating the project with Visual Studio in safe mode as well as creating a new project with a separate instance of Visual Studio attached for debugging. None of this has given me a clue as to what the problem might be.

Any idea what could be causing this issue? Or pointers on next steps to take?

Comment: What does the stack trace tell you? Where in the code does the exception occur? I have used the website template and don't get the error.

Comment: There is no stack trace. This happens during project creation process and just shows a message box. This is not when I try and run only when the project is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now upgrade to the full Visual Studio RTM version. That should fix your problems.